# Приоритеты операторов в записи в stack java

Tags: java

Программа упрощенный калькулятор. Есть метод в котором сравниваются приоритеты математических операторов, но я не знаю как это сделать. Должен выглядить примерно так:

```
char topOp = stack.peek();
if (приоритет op > приоритет topOp)
stack.push(op);
```

op -- это текущий, еще не записанный в stack оператор
Операторы с приоритетом:
+ : 1, - : 1, * : 2, / : 2, % : 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создайте `Map`, заполните приоритетами

```
Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put('+', 1);
map.put('-', 1);
map.put('*', 2);
...
```

и пользуйтесь

```
if (map.get(op) > map.get(topOp))
```